# IIS URL Rewrite redirect to image to track email views

Tags: php, iis, url-rewriting, event-tracking

I am trying to build an email tracker based on the folder name that requests the image.

Example:

`https://www.example.com/image/123/spager.gif`

which need to be turned into this

`https://www.example.com/image/index.php?id=123`

which in return would serve the spacer.gif image.

Is this doable? And if yes, what am I missing?

So fare I got this:

web.config:

```
<rule name="email image tracker">
  <match url="^/image/([0-9]+)/spacer.gif">
  <action type="Rewrite" url="/image/index.php?id={R:1}" />
</rule>
```

index.php:

```
<?php
  header('Content-type: image/gif');
  $png_image = imagecreate(150, 150);
  imagecolorallocate($png_image, 15, 142, 210);
?>
```

but I am getting the error:

> The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.

and nothing in the log files that would help me get a hint on what is not working.

Comment: You should narrow down the error by loading `https://www.example.com/image/index.php?id=123` and seeing if an image is served. If you get the server error than the rewrite is unrelated... or a different issue you can resolve later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the config file inside the image folder, so dropped image as part of the match.

Also `<match ... />` was missing `/>` at the end.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="email_image_tracker" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^([0-9]+)/spacer.gif" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/i/index.php?id={R:1}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the request URL should be https://www.example.com/image/123/spacer.gif instead of https://www.example.com/image/123/spager.gif.

Secondly, if you are applying this rule. Please set it to

```
<match url="^image/([0-9]+)/spacer.gif">
```

instead of

```
<match url="^/image/([0-9]+)/spacer.gif">
```

The first slash"/" is not included in this segment.

```
<rule name="email image tracker" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^image/([0-9]+)/spacer.gif" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="/image/index.php?id={R:1}" />
            </rule>
```

This rule will rewrite /image/123/spacer.gif to /image/index.php?id=123. However, since the php page need to request resource from  https://www.example.com/image/123/spacer.gif. The image get corrupted because of the loop.

I think you could try to rewrite src tag inside the index.php with outbound rule.

[image]

[image]

Comment: ... `<match ... />` had only `>` at the end, and should have been `/>` at the end.